# Python with Folium maps error in the jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, folium

I'm trying to import a map into jupyter, but it doesn't want any to work.
I have two columns in a .csv called

```
df[['latitude', 'longitude']]
df.head(20)
```

and so far so good

when I try to represent it (I have made many attempts) or it gives me the empty out, or after waiting for about 10 minutes I have to restart jupyter because it blocks. I state that I have about 65000 rows of latitude and longitude, and the code I use is this:

```
m = folium.Map([41.4, 12.7], zoom_start=8)
m
```

I see the map correctly

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
folium.Marker([row['latitude'], row['longitude']], 
              #popup=row['Location'],
              icon=folium.Icon(icon='cloud')
             ).add_to(m)
m
```

I get the problems I described above ....
Thanks to those who can help me

Comment: Could you please add the output of `df.head(20)`?

Comment: `41.454 12.620` in  `df[latitude],  df[longitude] ` but I noticed that the map is displayed after about 20 minutes. I think the problem is too much data? possible?

Comment: it is displayed but slowing down the whole jupyter page

Comment: yes that is the problem. You got to many data points which you want to show,

Comment: Is there any workaround to solve the problem? the page is unusable due to its slowness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `FastMarkerCluster`.

```
import folium
from folium import plugins

locations = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    locations.append([row['latitude'], row['longitude'])

marker_cluster = plugins.FastMarkerCluster(locations).add_to(m)

m
```

Now your points are clustered first and the single locations will be visible if you zoom in.

Comment: `folium.plugins.HeatMap(locations, name="heatmap").add_to(m)`
`folium.plugins.FastMarkerCluster(locations, name='cluster').add_to(m)`
`folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)`
`m`

Comment: I solved it in this way by adding a Heatmap, now the problem is that I would like the Radio Buttons Not the checked boxes! Could you tell me how to proceed. Thanks again!